# Как «in 6 hours» на «6 hours ago» переделать на JS или jquery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Как изменить строку с датой добавления поста с "in 6 hours" на "6 hours ago"

Comment: `var str = "in 6 hours"; str = "6 hours ago";` Это я к чему - непонятно где и по какому правилу вы хотите менять строки.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду запись в формате "in N hours" приводить к формату "N hours ago"? А стоит ли эту задачу вообще решать на фронт-энде?

Comment: Явно где-то в вашем коде есть функция, которая переоформляет дату в такой "человекочитаемый" вид. Найдите ее и поменяйте. Или скопируйте сюда кусок этой функции, вам помогут разобраться.

Answer (score 1):

```
function changeString(input) {
    var re = /\d+/;
    var matches = input.match(re);
    if (!matches) return;
    return matches[0] + " hours ago";
}
var output = changeString("in 6 hours");
console.log(output);
```